# CDetailView's value pagination in YII

Tags: php, yii, pagination, cdetailview

I would like to know if it is possible to create a pagination of only one value/row of CDetailView in YII. I have a table (`tbl_articles`), in which has a column called `text`. The content of `text` is quite long and I would like to create a pagination only for it. This pagination has to be only for views/articles/views. 
Do you think this is possible? Can someone give me some tips or show me a tutorial? I have search for it, but could not find anything.

Comment: Do you have a model to show? Some code perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @PrabowoMurti , but I decided to create two tables instead, I'll have only to join the two tables. I think it'll be easier this way.